# Read interface param (p []byte) turns byte length to 512 after reading

Tags: go

Here's the example code:
Definition of Person

```
type Person struct {
   Data string
   done bool
}
```

Implement Write

```
func (person *Person) Write(p []byte) (int,error) {
    person.Data = string(p)
    return len(p), nil
}
```

Implement Read

```
func (person *Person) Read(p []byte) (int,error) {
    if person.done {
        return 0, io.EOF
    }

    for index, b := range []byte(person.Data) {
        p[index] = b
    }
    // len(p) = 512 <- length p []byte
    person.done = true
    return len(person.Data), nil
}
```

Write some data

```
func writeTo(out io.Writer) error {
    if _, err := out.Write([]byte("test")); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Println("Write done")
    return nil
}
```

main

```
func main() {
    p := &Person{}
    
    writeTo(p)

    s, err := ioutil.ReadAll(p)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println("result:",string(s),len(s))
}
```

As noticed that **p []byte** length is 512.
I want to understand why it turns to 512 length.

Comment: Post the definition of `Person`

Comment: too early to make this call, but if you are reading a byte stream, you should know beforehand, how long the data is, i.e. there should be `Data` and the size of it. Right now you are reading the entire size of `person.Data` which seems it is set to 512

Comment: To understand why p has a particular length you have to inspect the caller. // You should replace the for loop with [the `copy` built-in](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code calls `ReadAll`:

```
s, err := ioutil.ReadAll(p)
```

`ReadAll` essentially works like this:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   // first, make an empty slice, with a reserve space of 512
   b := make([]byte, 0, 512)
   // then, write data into the reserve space
   n := copy(b[:cap(b)], "north")
   // then, increase the slice to how much data was just written
   b = b[:n]
   // 5 [110 111 114 116 104]
   fmt.Println(n, b)
}
```

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.16.3/src/io/io.go#L626